# wso2 identity server 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have both my wso2 api manager and wso2 identity server running on the same instance .So I wanted my wso2 identity server to run at port 9444. I restarted my wso2 identity server after adding an offset of 1 in the carbon.xml.
I am getting a 502 Bad gateway error when I try to access my carbon console on 9444 port or any other port.
Are there other places where I need to change the port in the wso2 identity server. I have not changed the port settings in any other config files in the identity server .They are still showing the default port settings

Answer (score 0):

You have to change only port offset in carbon.xml for WSO2 Identity Server. Have a look [1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products

Comment: I have done the same. When I do not apply any offset and shut down my api manager service and start identity server,i can access identity server carbon console.When I add an offset of 1 in the carbon.xml and restart my identity server , i am not able to browser the carbon console .I get 502 bad gateway error. My api manager service is still stopped and only identity server service is running on the instance.

Comment: "sudo netstat -tnulp|grep 9444" execute the command and post result

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9444            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29140/java

Comment: tcp        0       0 0.0.0.0:9444             0.0.0.0:*                LISTEN       29140/java

Comment: its up and running, check carbon console for any errors

Comment: @Sajith When we apply an offset of 1 in carbon.xml in identity server do we need to do any additional configuration changes for samlsso to be running on port 9444 . The link https://<<domain>>:9444/identity/metadata/saml2 , still shows sign on url as https://<<domain>>:9443/samlsso and when the carbon console link is browsed it gets redirected to https://<<domain>>:9444/samlsso , with error 405 -method not allowed